# Weierstrass Theorem - open domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As I understand it, Weierstrass Theorem states that a function f will attain maximum/minimum values on a domain D if D is compact and f is continuous. Does this necessarily mean that a function **will not attain a maximum/minimum value** if either of the domain conditions does not hold (i.e. non-compact domain, discontinuous f)?

Comment: No, there are functions attaining maximum and minimum on open intervals as well (for example constant functions). But the theorem states that on an open interval it could be possible to find a continuous function that does not attain a maximum or minimum, for example $f(x)= \frac 1x$ on $(0,1)$

Comment: No, it does not mean that. It just means that you the Weiestrass Extremal Theorem cannot tell you if the function attains an extrema within that domain, although you could use other information on the function and domain to determine if the extrema is within the domain.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the two conditions aren't necessary. Take a function with domain $(-1,1)$ or $\mathbb{R}$ (not compact) with values $0$ everywhere except in $x=0$ with value $1$ (not continuous). This is limited and it has maximum and minimum.

A continuous function without compact domain could be unlimited and could haven't maximum or minimum, for example $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x$ is continuous and it has a non compact domain, it has neither maximum or minimum.

A function with compact domain but not continuous is for example $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=1/x$ for $x\in]0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[-1,0]$ hasn't maximum.